# numbers stored as integers while copying from another sheet, error "type mismatch"

Tags: vba

I am doing macro that is copying data from some files and pasting it into new one. During that process, numbers copied are changed to text, and cannot be changed back (i tried couple of tricks), heres the code responsible for copying

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(koniec, 6)).Copy


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True

Workbooks("results").Activate
Worksheets.Add().Name = enclosedValue
Worksheets(enclosedValue).Activate
Sheets(enclosedValue).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

When I try to change the values in VBA i get "type mismatch" error. Do you have any ideas how to simplify it?

For example, this code is causing error - type mismatch

```
 Range("c13").Value = CDbl(Range("c13").Value)
```

Comment: Use explicit sheet references not activesheet. You are just asking for bugs otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(koniec, 6)).Copy
```

To this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(koniec, 6)).Copy
End With
```

and it should work. Pay attention to the dots in front of the `Cells()`. Without the dots, the VBA takes into account either the `ActiveSheet` or the sheet in which the code is.

If the Parent Sheet is not `Sheet1`, then there is an error coming.

Comment: I still get "number stored as text" message

Comment: Where do you get this? Try changing `koniec` to something else.

Comment: after copying, data in parent files is in numeric form, in new file it is not